# Android align menu items in NavigationView

Tags: android

this xml view is my simple `NavigationView` with some menu items into that. but i can not set `gravity` to `RIGHT` items

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/vNavigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/view_global_menu_header"
            app:itemIconTint="#8b8b8b"
            app:itemTextColor="#666666"
            android:gravity="right"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

`gravity="right"` and `layout_gravity="right"` dont work correctly and i can not find any document about how to change menu items gravity

my DrawerMenu Items structure:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/menu_group_2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_about"
            android:title="About" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` is designed to provide easy support for creating a navigation drawer that is compliant with the Material design specifications. Those specifications call for text to be left-aligned.

Since `NavigationView` does not offer support for custom row layouts, you cannot easily change this.

Instead, you should create your own layout for the drawer in your `DrawerLayout`. The good news is that `NavigationView` isn't particularly special- it mostly just wraps a `ListView` and provides the default Material styling that I mentioned. If you want to clone the functionality of `NavigationView`, you can find the (out of date) [source on GitHub](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/NavigationDrawerView.java).

Comment: thanks sir. i must be use your mentioned link as `NavigationDrawerView` class instead of `NavigationView` ? can you introducing some own layout for Drawelayout with some menu items?

Comment: That source is out of date. Between when Google posted that source code and when they released the design support library, they renamed the View.

Comment: can you introducing some own layout for Drawelayout with some menu items?

Comment: The source code I linked you to demonstrates how the support library engineers create a ListView using a menu resource.